# Inverse relation ;)

Tags: elementary-functions

wise people!

A question of someone who doesn't know too much about Maths!

You all know that:

**Δx . Δp ≥ h/2**

I have found that formula written as:

The possible variation of the position of a body in an *inverse relation* to the possible variation of the momentum is equal or greater than ... (The rest doesn't matter)

Is if that right? Is is really there an "inverse relation"?

Many thanks for your time!

;)

Comment: Annoyed comment >:(

Answer (score 1):

If two quantities, $x$ and $y$, are related by a law $$ x\cdot y = K$$(where $K$ is a constant), then $$ x = K/y.$$ If you plug in a few values you can see that this means that when $y$ gets smaller then $x$ gets larger, and when $y$ gets larger $x$ gets smaller. That's what it means to have an inverse relationship.

By the way, "relationship" is a pretty general term, and would also apply if, for example, $(x^2+1)(y^2+3) = 5$ held, as it exhibits the same "if one goes up the other goes down" behavior. The rule "$x\cdot y = K$" is a very specific one, and you can use the term "inverse proportion" (as suggested by mauro's comment) to be more precise.

Comment: Many thanks, Mr JonathanZ!

Comment: @HelenaS, if you think this answers your question you can accept this answer by clicking on the check mark on the left-hand side below the up- and down- arrow.